# Error after Importing java Maven projects into Eclipse juno on Mac?

Tags: maven

I imported the maven projects from perforce in to eclipse juno on Mac and refreshed and updated dependencies as well, but still errors are shown on all the maven projects not on java classes.
am using mac 10.7.4 with JSE 1.6.

In Problems portal am getting warning description as..

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

But if i import the same projects on windows with jdk 1.6, its working fine, no errors shown.
Pls suggest.

Comment: Check eclipse configuration and take a look JRE configured.

Comment: having JSE 1.6, on installed jre's location on eclipse. do i need to point to jdk or jre 1.5??

Comment: Try right-click your project, choose Properties - Java Compiler, change Compiler compliance level to 1.6.

Comment: I changed the Java Compiler, change Compiler compliance level to 1.6, but still same problem...